# flask get argument with special character and white spaces in it using URL

Tags: python, flask

I am using flask URL to get parameters from front to back to pass it to query and it is working great with simple strings without any special character or space in it. However, when I pass **"Historic_data CBD_3 (10WAY_10.0mWx59.0mW:28)"** , it is not working. (string with special character like () . : and with white space)

I am running it on Linux. I tested it on windows and it was fine.

```
front 
@app.route('/design/<string:des>')
callback
/design/Historic_Intersection%20CBD_3%20(3WAY_6.0mWx5.0mW:10)
```

I think URL encoding is being problem here, any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead using url pass you can pass it with `$.ajax({data: data})`

```
let data_to_back = "Historic_data CBD_3 (10WAY_10.0mWx59.0mW:28)"
$.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'pass/design/',
            dataType: "json",
            data: data)}
```

Answer (score 2):

See `quote` and  `unquote`  in urllib.parse. https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.quote

Basically, URLs cannot have certain characters in them (like spaces), so if your URL contains one of these bad characters, it gets replaced, which is what you observe. The `quote` function takes any string and gives you the URL version of it. The `unquote` takes the URL version and gives you back the original.

If you need to do the same thing in query parameters, use `quote_plus` and `unquote_plus` instead.